# Why is QLocale.system() showing a different locale than one constructed from language code?

Tags: pyqt5, localization, internationalization

My system locale is Portuguese (Brazil):

```py
>>> sys_locale = QLocale.system()
>>> QLocale.languageToString(sys_locale.language())
'Portuguese'
>>> QLocale.countryToString(sys_locale.country())
'Brazil'
```

When comparing it to a `QLocale` constructed with the language code that represents it, the result is not equal:

```py
>>> sys_locale == QLocale('pt_BR')
False
```

Constructing a `QLocale` with parameters from system locale works, though:

```py
>>> pt_br = QLocale(sys_locale.language(), sys_locale.country())
>>> pt_br == QLocale('pt_BR')
True
```

Why is that?

Comment: Because `QLocale(name)` constructs a locale with *default values*. If your system locale does not use all the defaults, it won't compare equal. To see what differs, you'd need to compare all the properties individually.

Comment: One of those locales might have subtle differences, as the string constructor for the locale uses default settings set by Qt based on that string, while the system might have other settings. For instance, on my computer [`uiLanguages()`] returns `['it-IT']` for the `system()` locale, but with `QLocale('it_IT')` it returns `['it', 'it-IT', 'it-Latn-IT']`. In Italy, the decimal separator is the comma, but if I decide to use the dot for my system, those locales would differ anyway even if `uiLanguages()` would match, and even if they use the same country and language.

Comment: Hmm, I see. I didn't know you can change stuff like that on your system, as I personally never cared about changing it. I thought locale was predefined, that is, everyone using 'it_IT' would get commas as the decimal separator.

Comment: As for `QLocale`, the only parameters I can pass upon construction are language, script, and country. I checked `QLocale('pt_BR').script()` and it's same as that of system locale. That means the difference must be somewhere else, such as the character used for decimal separator. But I can't set it on construction of `QLocale`, nor is there a `set*()` method in it. I guess there's no way of getting them to compare equal then?

Comment: @GiovanniL The country/language locale *is* considered default, and that's one of the many aspects for which locales **must** be considered with extreme care. For instance, I'm Italian, and while I'm used to the comma as decimal separator (even in spoken language, as "floating point" is known as "virgola mobile", something like "movable comma"), my "programmer-side" completely hates it. When I have to speak out a float value, I "say" the comma since it's both habit and convention, but I think about the dot. That said, it completely depends on the purpose for which you need to compare locales.

Comment: @GiovanniL So, I suggest you to expand your question by [edit]ing it and explain *why* you need to compare locales: the subject is so complex that it's impossible to give you a more comprehensive answer unless you explain why you need that comparison. For instance, if you just need to compare the country/language pair, then just compare the `locale.language()` and/or `locale.country()`. As said, locales are an extremely complex matter, and are also very dependent on the *region* and *habit* of the user.

Comment: What you're really asking is whether two locales are *similar* according to your own criteria. Qt very sensibly doesn't try to guess what your criteria are, so its `==` operator compares *everything*. If your requirements are looser than that, you will need to compare just those properties that fit your own criteria (e.g. `(sysloc.country(), syslocal.language()) == (other.country(), other.language())`). In this regard, `QLocale` works exactly same as e.g. `QFont`. And this is a highly desirable feature, since it makes it possible to respect user-preferences without worrying about the details.

Comment: I'm developing an application that has a language menu. Every `QAction` in that menu corresponds to a language that has an available translation. I want to call `QAction.setChecked()` if a locale is same as the system's to indicate the language currently in use. That's when I found out my system locale and `QLocale('pt_BR')` don't compare equal. Fortunately for my use case, comparing language and country is sufficient, and that's what I did. I asked this question to understand why comparison of locales didn't work, though.

Comment: For reference, this is the article I'm following, although with a few modifications: https://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1405555&seqNum=3